# Query to update particular column field in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried the following queries to change the column field of the table 'role' from 'Admin' to 'Administrator'. I am not informed about the values of id. my table 'role' contains two columns 'name' and 'id'.
None of the queries worked. Where am I going wrong?

```
update table role set name=replace('Administrator','Admin');
update table role set name='Administrator' where name='Admin';
select replace('Admin','Administrator') from role;
```

Comment: the second query should do the job, what is the problem?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Are you sure? ;-)

Comment: No.. there is no "update table" syntax in the doc.

Answer (score 4):

You don't use a `table` keyword so the second example is almost correct

```
update role set name='Administrator' where name='Admin';
```

Answer (score 2):

The second would be the standard way:

```
update role  -- "table" is not appropriate
    set name = 'Administrator'
    where name = 'Admin';
```

My guess is that you have no row that matches the condition -- presumably because of bad/hidden characters in `name`.  Try this:

```
select *
from role
where name = 'Admin';
```

If this returns no rows, then try `like`:

```
where name like 'Admin%'
where name like '%Admin'
where name like '%Admin%'
```

Or maybe, using `regexp`:

```
where name regexp '[[:<:]]admin[[:>:]]'
```

(note that `regexp` is, by default, not case sensitive)

If one of these matches the row you want, then use it in the `update`.

Answer (score -2):

you need to alter the table structure so the Mysql comand should be:

```
ALTER TABLE role CHANGE Admin Administrator [Admin column data type]
```

Comment: You have completely misunderstood the question, it has nothing to do with altering the table but instead updating the data in the table